# Set the title of a custom post automatically by using info from custom fields?

Tags: plugins, custom-post-types

I've set up a CPT via a plugin, including custom fields for first and last name, so I'd like to automatically make the post title "First Name + ' ' + Last Name".

This post almost got me there:

[How To Set Custom Post Type Title Without Supports](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/88655/how-to-set-custom-post-type-title-without-supports)

But my version (adapted code below) creates a title called "Array Array".

```
add_filter( 'save_post_practitioners', 'hexagon_practitioner_set_title', 10, 3 );
function hexagon_practitioner_set_title ( $post_id, $post, $update ){
    //This temporarily removes filter to prevent infinite loops
    remove_filter( 'save_post_practitioners', __FUNCTION__ );

    //get first and last name meta
    $first = get_metadata( 'first_name', $post_id ); //meta for first name
    $last = get_metadata( 'last_name', $post_id );   //meta for last name

    $title = $first . ' ' . $last;

    //update title
    wp_update_post( array( 'ID'=>$post_id, 'post_title'=>$title ) );

    //redo filter
    add_filter( 'save_post_practitioners', __FUNCTION__, 10, 3 );
}
```

I've delved into the functions involved but there seem to be many competing solutions that aren't quite what I'm looking for. What am I getting wrong?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue with your code is that the get_metadata() function returns an array of values, not a single value. So when you concatenate $first and $last variables in this line $title = $first . ' ' . $last;, you are actually concatenating two arrays, which results in the "Array Array" title.

To fix this, you can use the get_post_meta() function instead of get_metadata() to retrieve the first and last name values as follows:

```
$first = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'first_name', true ); //meta for first name
$last = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'last_name', true );   //meta for last name
```

The third parameter true in the get_post_meta() function specifies that you want to retrieve a single value instead of an array of values.

Here's the updated code:

```
add_filter( 'save_post_practitioners', 'hexagon_practitioner_set_title', 
10, 3 );
function hexagon_practitioner_set_title ( $post_id, $post, $update ){
//This temporarily removes filter to prevent infinite loops
remove_filter( 'save_post_practitioners', __FUNCTION__ );

//get first and last name meta
$first = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'first_name', true ); //meta for first 
name
$last = get_post_meta( $post_id, 'last_name', true );   //meta for last 
name

$title = $first . ' ' . $last;

//update title
wp_update_post( array( 'ID'=>$post_id, 'post_title'=>$title ) );

//redo filter
add_filter( 'save_post_practitioners', __FUNCTION__, 10, 3 );
}
```

This should set the post title to "First Name Last Name" as you intended.

Comment: Thanks @techshqq! Got it to work after a little fiddling, discovering I'd referenced my post type incorrectly in the filter name, calling it "save_post_practitioners" not "save_post_practitioner". I assume I should use whatever I put in 'singular_name', not 'name', in my CPT $labels array?

Comment: One last wrinkle: I'd like the slug to reflect the same info as well, but I'm only getting a numeric one. [This link] (https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/94364/set-post-title-from-two-meta-fields/) discusses the issue, but I'm not sure how to integrate it into my own code.

Comment: @AdamAbrams I thought I should help, so: 1) "*I assume I should use whatever I put in 'singular_name'*" - no, it's the first parameter passed to [`register_post_type()`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/#parameters), but since you added your CPT using a plugin, then you need to check its documentation regarding which one is the post type name. 2) You can update the slug by adding `'post_name' => '<slug here>'` to your args (the array you pass to `wp_update_post()`). So, for example, you can use `'post_name' => sanitize_title( $title ),`.

Comment: Thanks @SallyCJ ! That works great for updating the slug. As for 1) though: I created the plugin, but that's just because it seemed the best-practice way to add the CPT code. So no documentation... But in the code for adding the CPT, the "$args = array()" part begins like this: `label' => __( 'Practitioners', 'text_domain' ),` i.e. the plural, "practitioners". Yet my code for setting the title/slug only works if I use `save_post_practitioner` - singular.

Comment: @AdamAbrams In short, if you used `register_post_type( 'practitioner',`, then the post type name/slug is `practitioner`. If it's `register_post_type( 'practitioners',` (note the "s"), then the post type is `practitioners`. If you actually did use the plural "practitioners", but the one that worked was "practitioner", then that's weird  However, if you need further assistance with that, you should post another question. :)

Comment: Thanks. Yes I realize I’ve strayed pretty far from the original question.  I’ll study this further and post a fresh question if I need to.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the 'single' parameter to `true`. It's the 4th parameter and defaults to `false` which *returns an array*, and thus you got `Array Array` because you did not set that parameter (to `true`).

Additionally, you incorrectly used `get_metadata()` and received either an **empty array** or an array of **all metadata** (`first_name`, `last_name`, etc.) for the specific post. See the documentation for the correct syntax, where the 1st parameter is actually the meta **type** and not the meta key/name:

https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_metadata/

So in your case, the meta type is `post`, and the correct syntax is:

```php
$first = get_metadata( 'post', $post_id, 'first_name', true );
$last  = get_metadata( 'post', $post_id, 'last_name', true );
```

Comment: Hmm, with that change, it puts nothing in the post title field, in fact it forces it to be empty. I'll look closer at the get_metadata article though.

Comment: It's returning an empty string meaning it cannot find the meta value.  And your original attempt was returning an empty array.