# Is there a way to modify a core admin page table?

Tags: customization

I would like to modify the "pages" section of WordPress dashboard to add this custom column "views" to tell how many times one page was viewed. Is there a way to do this?

[image: custom dashboard]

Comment: You should be able to use the [`manage_pages_columns`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/manage_pages_columns/) filter to add new columns to the page list table.

Comment: Adding custom columns is the easy part. You need to determine how you are calculating views and where to store that data first.  Printing that value in a custom column will be simple after that.  There are plugins that handle page/post views but that is off-topic here.  What have you tried so far?

Comment: May this link will helpful for you to get some ideas https://gretathemes.com/count-post-views/.

Comment: See this q/a to find a solid solution https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/27870/add-column-to-pages-table If you look about the hook `manage_posts_columns` you will find several tutorials, like https://wpengineer.com/1960/display-post-thumbnail-post-page-overview/

Comment: All your posts have helped me a lot! I could add a new column and understand overall wordpress core, thanks a lot! For any reason, I can't update my views even following the https://gretathemes.com/count-post-views/ link but I will try harder. Thanks guys!